# MatteBorder does not work well with right-to-left component orientation

Tags: java, swing

I have problems getting MatteBorder to work with right-to-left component orientation. The code below illustrates the problem.

I place one JPanel inside another JPanel. Both JPanels have a MatteBorder. The inner border has thickness 10,10,10,10 whereas the outer border has thickness 20,20,20,10 (note that the outer border is asymmetrical).

If the JPanels have a component orientation of LEFT_TO_RIGHT, everything looks nice; but if the orientation is RIGHT_TO_LEFT, the borders overlap.

[image: Overlapping borders]

Consider the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Xyzzy extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Xyzzy frame = new Xyzzy();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 0, 5));
                frame.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT); 

                {
                    JPanel outer = new JPanel();
                    outer.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 0, 5));
                    outer.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT); 
                    outer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(20, 20, 20, 10, Color.black));

                    JPanel inner = new JPanel();
                    inner.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 0, 5));
                    inner.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT); 
                    inner.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10, 10, 10, 10, Color.red));

                    inner.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,10)));
                    outer.add(inner);
                    frame.add(outer);
                }

                {
                    JPanel outer = new JPanel();
                    outer.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 5));
                    outer.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT); 
                    outer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(20, 20, 20, 10, Color.blue));

                    JPanel inner = new JPanel();
                    inner.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 5));
                    inner.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT); 
                    inner.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10, 10, 10, 10, Color.yellow));

                    inner.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,10)));
                    outer.add(inner);
                    frame.add(outer);
                }

                frame.setSize(600, 600);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The first half of the code generates RIGHT_TO_LEFT JPanels with black and red borders, the second half generates LEFT_TO_RIGHT JPanels with yellow and blue borders. If you run the program you will see the yellow borders nicely within in the blue borders, but the red borders overlap the black ones.

Why?

Comment: I would start with using FLowLayout.LEADING/TRAILING instead of LEFT/RIGHT and applyComponentOrientation instead of set (perhaps as last thing you do).

Comment: I'm sorry, Walter, even with the changes you suggest, I still cannot get the RIGHT_TO_LEFT orientation to place the red border inside the black one.

Comment: looks like a bug to me - FlowLayout seems to get confused with asymetric insets in RToL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this is *not* an answer - just an extended comment with code :-)

Stripped out a bit from the OPs example, to concentrate on the FlowLayout-issue-with-asym-borders-in-RToL - added a label instead of the rigid area to better (for me :-) see where it is located. The layout is simply going nuts ...

```
public void run() {
    MatteBorderCO frame = new MatteBorderCO();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

    frame.add(createRToLPanel(50, 100, true));
    frame.add(createRToLPanel(100, 100, true));
    frame.add(createRToLPanel(100, 50, true));

    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private JPanel createRToLPanel(int leftInset, int rightInset, boolean matte) {
    JPanel outer = new JPanel();
    Border asymBorder = matte ? 
            BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(20, leftInset, 20, rightInset, Color.black) :
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, leftInset, 20, rightInset)    ;
    outer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            asymBorder, BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED)
    ));

    JPanel inner = new JPanel();
    inner.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    inner.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
    inner.add(new JLabel("RToL"));
    outer.add(inner);
    outer.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    return outer;
}
```

**Edit**

Culprit is an incorrect calculation of location in flowLayout.moveComponents:

```
   if (ltr) {
        m.setLocation(x, cy);
   } else { // RtoL orientation
        // here's the error: location is adjusted relative to the target width
        // without taking the insets into account ... 
        m.setLocation(target.width - x - m.width, cy);
   }
```

**Edit 2**

removed the assumed "simple" fix - not good enough ;-)

**Edit 3**

couldn't resist, here's a FixedFlowLayout (formally untested, just used in the example above which looks fine with it!)

```
public static class FixedFlowLayout extends FlowLayout {

    /**
     * C&p mostly - RToL border fix implemented.
     */
    protected int moveComponents(Container target, int x, int y, int width,
            int height, int rowStart, int rowEnd, boolean ltr,
            boolean useBaseline, int[] ascent, int[] descent) {
        switch (getAlignment()) {
        case LEFT:
            x += ltr ? 0 : width;
            break;
        case CENTER:
            x += width / 2;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            x += ltr ? width : 0;
            break;
        case LEADING:
            break;
        case TRAILING:
            x += width;
            break;
        }
        int maxAscent = 0;
        int nonbaselineHeight = 0;
        int baselineOffset = 0;
        if (useBaseline) {
            int maxDescent = 0;
            for (int i = rowStart; i < rowEnd; i++) {
                Component m = target.getComponent(i);
                if (m.isVisible()) {
                    if (ascent[i] >= 0) {
                        maxAscent = Math.max(maxAscent, ascent[i]);
                        maxDescent = Math.max(maxDescent, descent[i]);
                    } else {
                        nonbaselineHeight = Math.max(m.getHeight(),
                                nonbaselineHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
            height = Math.max(maxAscent + maxDescent, nonbaselineHeight);
            baselineOffset = (height - maxAscent - maxDescent) / 2;
        }

        int right = target.getWidth() - target.getInsets().right - getHgap();

        for (int i = rowStart; i < rowEnd; i++) {
            Component m = target.getComponent(i);
            if (m.isVisible()) {
                int cy;
                if (useBaseline && ascent[i] >= 0) {
                    cy = y + baselineOffset + maxAscent - ascent[i];
                } else {
                    cy = y + (height - m.getHeight()) / 2;
                }
                if (ltr) {
                    m.setLocation(x, cy);
                    x += m.getWidth() + getHgap();
                } else {
                    m.setLocation(right - m.getWidth(), cy);
                    right -= m.getWidth() + getHgap();
                }
            }
        }
        return height;
    }

    /**
     * C&p, to be able to call the fixed moveComponent.
     */
    @Override
    public void layoutContainer(Container target) {
        synchronized (target.getTreeLock()) {
            Insets insets = target.getInsets();
            int maxwidth = target.getWidth()
                    - (insets.left + insets.right + getHgap() * 2);
            int nmembers = target.getComponentCount();
            int x = 0, y = insets.top + getVgap();
            int rowh = 0, start = 0;

            boolean ltr = target.getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight();

            boolean useBaseline = getAlignOnBaseline();
            int[] ascent = null;
            int[] descent = null;

            if (useBaseline) {
                ascent = new int[nmembers];
                descent = new int[nmembers];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < nmembers; i++) {
                Component m = target.getComponent(i);
                if (m.isVisible()) {
                    Dimension d = m.getPreferredSize();
                    m.setSize(d.width, d.height);

                    if (useBaseline) {
                        int baseline = m.getBaseline(d.width, d.height);
                        if (baseline >= 0) {
                            ascent[i] = baseline;
                            descent[i] = d.height - baseline;
                        } else {
                            ascent[i] = -1;
                        }
                    }
                    if ((x == 0) || ((x + d.width) <= maxwidth)) {
                        if (x > 0) {
                            x += getHgap();
                        }
                        x += d.width;
                        rowh = Math.max(rowh, d.height);
                    } else {
                        rowh = moveComponents(target, insets.left + getHgap(),
                                y, maxwidth - x, rowh, start, i, ltr,
                                useBaseline, ascent, descent);
                        x = d.width;
                        y += getVgap() + rowh;
                        rowh = d.height;
                        start = i;
                    }
                }
            }
            moveComponents(target, insets.left + getHgap(), y, maxwidth - x,
                    rowh, start, nmembers, ltr, useBaseline, ascent,
                    descent);
        }
    }

    public FixedFlowLayout() {
    }

    public FixedFlowLayout(int align, int hgap, int vgap) {
        super(align, hgap, vgap);
    }

    public FixedFlowLayout(int align) {
        super(align);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, kleopatra, this piece of code illustrates it nicely. It looks beautiful with L-to-R and horrible with R-to-L. (For those of you want to try it. You should repace the `run` method in my original post with kleopatra's. Also, please note the kleopatra's `MatteBorderCO` is my `Xyzzy`.) So, if this really is a bug, do you have any idea how I can get around it?

Comment: One additional observation on the output from kleopatra's code: As far as I can see, the inner JPanel is positioned in the location where the "hole" in the outer JPanel _would have been_ if the layout had been L-to-R rather than R-to-L.

Comment: Thanks for the update, kleopatra. I'll be testing it shortly.

Comment: @ClausTøndering - careful: the assumed fix wasn't good enough. Sorry!

Comment: Okay, also I'm having some very basic problems here: How do I compile and use a java file which is part of `package java.awt` without having to compile everything in java.awt?

Comment: @ClausTøndering you can't - subclass and c&p the private parts

Comment: Thank you, kleopatra, for `FixedFlowLayout`. You have earned my eternal gratitude!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to solve the problem. (I'm basing the following on kleopatra's modified code.)

The trick is to insert an intermediate JPanel between the outer and inner JPanels. Keep the outer JPanel L-to-R and make the intermediate and inner JPanels R-to-L. You also need to specify zero-width gaps on the layout of the outer panel.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Xyzzy extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Xyzzy frame = new Xyzzy();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

                    frame.add(createRToLPanel(50, 100, true));
                    frame.add(createRToLPanel(100, 100, true));
                    frame.add(createRToLPanel(100, 50, true));

                    frame.setSize(600, 600);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }


                private JPanel createRToLPanel(int leftInset, int rightInset, boolean matte) {
                    JPanel outer = new JPanel();
                    Border asymBorder = matte ? 
                        BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(20, leftInset, 20, rightInset, Color.black) :
                        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, leftInset, 20, rightInset)    ;
                    outer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                                        asymBorder, BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED)
                                        ));

                    JPanel intermediate = new JPanel();
                    outer.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING,0,0)); 
                    outer.add(intermediate);

                    JPanel inner = new JPanel();
                    inner.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                    inner.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
                    inner.add(new JLabel("RToL1"));
                    inner.add(new JLabel("RToL2"));

                    intermediate.add(inner);
                    intermediate.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

                    return outer;
                }


            });
    }
}
```

In this code I add two JLabels to the inner JPanel to prove that the orientation really is R-to-L.

Silly, silly. But if this really *is* a bug, I can get around it in this manner.